# Google Maps API v3 Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I've been having a problem with the Google Maps API but only on Firefox. It is working perfectly fine for Chrome, IE8+ etc. But with Firefox I am getting this JS error:

```
ReferenceError: vd is not defined
```

I click on the JS related to the error which is part of the Google Maps JS and it comes up with a 404 error with this:

```
The requested URL /intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/17/7/main.js%20line%2052%20%3E%20eval was not found on this server.
```

Have any of you experienced this issue and is it fixable?

Thanks

Comment: Just experienced the same thing. Haven't had this happen before.

Comment: It seems to be happening on Mac Firefox as the Google Maps is working fine in Windows Firefox.

Comment: Intermittent - if it's a 404 error it's probably a problem with google's handling of requests (odd that it's only observed in Firefox). Doesn't appear to be anything you can do.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same thing - works in Chrome and IE, not working in Firefox. No idea why!

Comment: Same thing here...[this works](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple). But if I host it under a little node server...it no worky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Google has fixed this issue for Firefox, you do not need to update anything as it should have done it automatically. Thanks for the responses though.

Comment: Where did you find out that Google has fixed this issue in Firefox? I'm still having the issue. Like your situation, it works in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a Firefox without extension :

quote :

2) Make sure you don't have any of the following programs installed:
  - Skype extension for Firefox
  - NoScript/AdBlock extensions for Firefox
  - if2k porn filter (for MacOS X)
 These are known to interfere with Maps and prevent it from loading.

from:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/tfsofp_XXQI%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately I do not have any of those extensions - I don't usually use Firefox unless its for testing, the only extension I have is firebug.